# Nest+GRPC proto file response structure

Tags: api, nestjs, grpc, proto, grpc-node

i'm using nest and GRPC microservice to build my backend.

so first i have created rest api and now i'm converting it to GRPC call.

so my api response is as follows:

```
{
"data": {
    "2-2-2-2": [             //id
        [
            24.942795,       //lat
            60.17088         //lng
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

```
protofile:

    syntax = "proto3";
package LocationTracking;

service LocationTrackingService {
  rpc getLocations(GetLocationInputs) returns (GetLocationResponse);
 
}

     message GetLocationInputs {
    string assetIds = 1;
    optional string from = 4;
    optional string to = 5;
    
  }

  message GetLocationResponse {
   
  }
```

so how should i structure GetLocationResponse  message for this kind of response?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Maps](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps) type to define your `GetLocationResponse` and a message `Location` to define your two values

Example

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package location.tracking

message Location {
    double lat;
    double lng;
}

service LocationTrackingService {
  rpc getLocations(GetLocationRequest) returns (GetLocationResponse);
}

message GetLocationRequest {
  string assetIds = 1;
  optional string from = 4;
  optional string to = 5;  
}

message GetLocationResponse {
  map<string, Location> data = 1;   
}
```

I also recommend you [Google naming convention](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/naming_convention#method_names) to keep a consistant standard naming in your protobuf.